# What is a good way to hack apacite to show DOIs in apa 6th style?

Tags: bibtex, apa-style, doi

I've needed to add doi's to the end of my references in order to comply with APA 6th edition.

At first, I found this [discussion about DOIs and apacite](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=6608), but it didn't really provide a solution. After reading the [apacite manual](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=apacite&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCwQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmirror.ctan.org%2Fbiblio%2Fbibtex%2Fcontrib%2Fapacite%2Fapacite.pdf&ei=xZc0T6bmK46fiAefxuT1AQ&usg=AFQjCNEIIj28bGm9VYZoOjMHs5WSweaz1A&sig2=vRHa0-rEkVu_TdyWTjLjFA) and then the [apacite.sty](http://www.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/apacite/apacite.sty) file, I found out about how to apply modifications.

In the end I've adopted a hack:

I place the doi in the `note` field of the each bibtex reference. I then add the following command to my document preamble in order to prevent the doi from being enclosed in brackets.

```
\renewcommand{\APACrefnote}[1]{%
  \ifx\@empty#1\@empty
  \else
    {#1}%
  \fi
}
```

It seems to work, but it also feels like a bit of hack.

- Can you see any problems with the above approach?
- Is there a better option at this point for incorporating dois into apa references?

Comment: I suppose the problem, deep down, is caused by the fact that the `apacite.bst` file doesn't recognize -- and hence doesn't process -- the "doi" field. Hopefully, this omission will be addressed in an update to this otherwise very well designed bibliography style file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biblatex-apa style for BibLaTeX is almost fully compliant with APA6. The only limitation is related to authors listed as ‘with.’ It includes DOIs by default based on the bib field DOI.